# How can ı save render green chanel?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I want to save my render's green chanel. How can do that?
Look at this image: https://prnt.sc/jftw5m

Comment: In Compositor there is "Separate RGB" node

Comment: Thank you very much. this is working! http://prntscr.com/jfu3z5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Serge L's answer is true.. Separate RBG is Answer.

[image]